# AKS Cluster - Automatic pulling of images hosted in Azure Container registry

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-registry

Is there a way to automate the pulling of images in AKS cluster from Azure Container registry whenever a new version is pushed to the registry?

Thanks in advance for the feedbacks.

Comment: This would typically be handled by your continuous delivery process. Implementing something that blindly pulls a new version of a container from a container registry and starts running it completely discounts the possibility for new orchestration requirements or breaking changes and should be avoided as a general practice.

Comment: I completely understand your point of view. I just would like to ease and fasten new versions deployment in a dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `:latest` tag on your image and `imagePullPolicy: Always`, any pod restart will use the latest image from your registry.

You could write a controller to periodically poll ACR and trigger a rolling restart (`kubectl rollout restart deployment..`) whenever there's a new `latest`. However, a more common approach would probably be to add the restart as an additional step to your CI/CD pipeline after publishing the new image.

Comment: That depends on your `imagePullPolicy`. It won't automatically re-pull a container with the `latest` tag if the tag already exists. That said, you should **never** rely on the `latest` tag. Implementing proper semver is absolutely critical when orchestrating containers in Kubernetes. This is also where the conversation turns to "GitOps" and whether you should consider implementing something like Flux.

Comment: Respectfully, never say never. OP might be looking for the simplest solution here, possibly for a non-production environment.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The easiest approach seems indeed to use pipelines. However, is there not some kubernetes operator that can be deployed as pod in the cluster to manage that? In the same way externalDNS can manage DNS records, do you know a tool to manage pods updates?